# I am trying to get letters to be centered over a line

Tags: vb.net, winforms

What I am attempting too accomplish is to get the letters that are in the array to be centered above each line that is written out, but I am currently not able to do that and unsure how to proceed.

```
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Dim understrekk(9), bokstav(9), utskrift, bokstUtskrift As String, i As Integer

    utskrift = ""
    bokstUtskrift = ""
    bokstav(0) = "a" : bokstav(1) = "b" : bokstav(2) = "c" : bokstav(3) = "d"
    bokstav(4) = "e" : bokstav(5) = "f" : bokstav(6) = "g" : bokstav(7) = "h"
    bokstav(8) = "i" : bokstav(9) = "j"

    'Handles the lines
    For Each b In bokstav
        utskrift = utskrift & "   ___"
    Next

    'Handles the letters
    For i = 0 To 9
        bokstUtskrift = bokstUtskrift & "   " & bokstav(i)
    Next

    Label1.Text = utskrift
    Label2.Text = bokstUtskrift
End Sub
```

This is also supposed to be used in a hangman game where the purpose is to show the lines so the user knows how many letters there are in the word. The word itself should come above the lines (and centered to each line, a line being the "   ___"), while at the same time being hidden since it is unknown to the user. When the user guesses 1 correct letter, that specific letter is supposed to show and so on. [This is how the user interface currently looks...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NXIyo.png)

Comment: Do you have only two labels, one for the chars and one for the line? I recommend creating one label (or textbox) for each character to guess and one for each underline. This makes it so much easier to address one char/underline position. You can even create the number of lables.dynamically.

Comment: @AlexB. It crossed my mind to try it, but I'm quite unsure how to actually do it. Not the most experienced when it comes to VB.

Comment: I will write an answer when I find a little time for it

Comment: @AlexB. Alright, thanks :D

Comment: By far the most obvious way to do this is with FontStyle.Underline, it will *always* line up correctly.  Pick a fixed-pitch font, use a space for a placeholder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok let´s divide the problem into several pieces.
- All functions/subs/variables are located in class `Form1`
- For the placeholder I chose `_` with `FontStyle.Underline` option. This will always underline in the correct place. Maybe a blank  should also work as a placeholder in this case.

**Determine the chars of the hangman word.**
 Store the result in a class variable so it can be used later when setting the underline placeholder or reveal a correct char.

```
private _solution as Char()

Private Sub setSolution(word As String)
     'Get chars from word and put into class variable
     _solution = word.ToArray()
End Sub
```

**Create a table-like panel layout. Each column contains one char:**

```
Private Sub createLayout(word As String)
        setSolution(word)

        'Create a panel layout with columns to get a proper distribution of chars
        Dim table As New TableLayoutPanel()
        table.Name = "tblHangmanWord"
        table.ColumnCount = _solution.Length
        table.RowCount = 1
        table.AutoSize = True
        table.ColumnStyles.Add(New ColumnStyle(SizeType.AutoSize))
        'Adjust the bounds to your needs
        table.SetBounds(40, 150, 400, 25)
        table.CellBorderStyle = TableLayoutPanelCellBorderStyle.None

        'Create labels which display placeholder first, add them to the panel. The array index of _solution correspond to the table columns index.
        For i As Integer = 0 To _solution.Length - 1
            Dim label As New Label()
            label.Name = "lblWord" & i.ToString
            label.Text = "___" 'Placeholder
            label.AutoSize = True
            label.Font = New Font(DefaultFont, FontStyle.Underline)
            'Add label to pabel
            table.Controls.Add(label)
        Next

        'Add panel to form
        Me.Controls.Add(table)
End Sub
```

**Handle a user´s click on a char button.**
Check which chars in the solution match with the button, then reveal the correct ones.

```
Private Sub btnM_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnM.Click
     'Get the indexes of the matches of the current button char
     Dim idxOfMatches = getIndexOfMatches(DirectCast(sender, Button).Text.First())
     'Show the correct chars in the grid
     revealMatchingChars(idxOfMatches)
End Sub

Private Function getIndexOfMatches(selected As Char) As Integer()
    Dim idxOfMatches As New List(Of Integer)

    For i As Integer = 0 To _solution.Length - 1
        If selected = _solution(i) Then
            idxOfMatches.Add(i)
        End If
    Next
    Return idxOfMatches.ToArray()
End Function

Private Sub revealMatchingChars(idxOfMatches As Integer())
    'Get the table panel layout
    Dim tbl = Me.Controls.OfType(Of TableLayoutPanel).Where(Function(t) t.Name = "tblHangmanWord").First()
    'reveal correct chars 
    For Each idx As Integer In idxOfMatches
        tbl.Controls(idx).Text = _solution(idx)
    Next
End Sub
```

**Putting all together and create a test layout:**

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    createLayout("Millencolin")
End Sub
```

[image: User clicked M]

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
'Handles the letters
For i = 0 To 9
    bokstUtskrift = bokstUtskrift & "   " & bokstav(i)
Next
```

Try this:

```
bokstUtskrift = "     " & String.Join("       ", bokstav)
```

Comment: Tried that as well now and it doesn't really solve it, still has the same issue.

Comment: @ForfA I just increased the gaps to 5 and 7 spaces from 4 and 5, and it seems to line up properly for me